# Keeping EC2 Free Instances Free

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I signed up for Amazon AWS's Free Tier instance. Everything works fine so far, but I'm a bit confused how to make sure I won't have to pay for it.

Specifically, I've been billed a bit for **"Elastic IP address not attached to a running instance per hour on a pro rata basis"**.

In the Management Console > Elastic IPs section, I have allocated a new Elastic IP and attached it to my instance. It seems that I can allocate 4 more addresses, but not attach them, this is only possible for one instance. How do I avoid being billed for unattached Elastic IPs? Is there even a way, if I have 5 Elastic IPs assigned to my account, but only have one instance?

I'm also not sure how the traffic usage reports work - I think I'm allowed "*15 GB of bandwidth out aggregated across all AWS services", but only if I use the Public DNS and not the Elastic IP. Is this correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since Amazon has only limited number of IP addresses available, they charge for every unattached Elastic IP address. It's protection against subscribers who allocate limited resources without using them, because they're free.

Conclusion: Allocate elastic IP addresses only for running instances, or accept that you are being billed (the charge is quite reasonable).

You can release addresses you don't need in [EC2 Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?s=Addresses).

Comment: So basically they assign 5 IPs to my account, of which I can only use 1 for free?

Comment: Why do you think that **they assign**? You allocate them on your own.

Comment: What I mean by assign is that they "reserve" 5 IPs for my account. Given that I only run one instance, I can only attach one of those IPs, so 4 go unattached and those are the ones I get charged for, correct?

Comment: Correct. You can attach more IPs to one running instance, but just the first one is free of charge. It's the same price as leaving it unassigned ($0.005 per hour).

Comment: Are you aware of the fact, that you can release the address you don't need in the [AWS console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home#s=Addresses)?

Comment: Yes, I only have one address attached. So that would mean no cost?

Comment: Not necessarily, you need to release all other addresses (my understanding is that you have 4 more unattached). So there is just one address left in the table.

Comment: I removed all the other Elastic IPs, now there is only one left. Thanks!